# What tools do you use when developing html?

Tags: html

What applications/services do you guys used when building websites/web applications with web technologies?  Windows?  Mac?

Comment: Do you mean what developping tools? Like Visual studio, Dreamweaver, ...

Comment: (-1) Vague question... IMO just targeted at "collectiong points". 
Do you mean front-edn development? Backend? And what "web technologies" - there are so many....
What kind of user profile? E.g. you could use Dreamweaver or MS Expression Web for frontend page editing if you're a designer, but you'll probaby feel much more comfortable in Visual Studio if you're a programmer)..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Linux Ubuntu Desktop Jaunty](http://www.ubuntu.com/)
- [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)
- [FireCookie](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6683)
- [Pixel Perfect](http://www.pixelperfectplugin.com/)
- [Web developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60)
- Zend Studio
- [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/)
- VirtualBox for testing with IE
- W3C Validator
- [Webstandards.org](http://www.webstandards.org/learn/reference/templates/) for getting (x)html templates

Answer (score 1):

Browser:

- Firefox: Firebug

  - Firequery (for better jQuery debugging)
  - Webdevlopper
  - Pixel Perfect
  - Tiny HTML Validator
- Chrome:

  - The DEV tools for measuring my loading times.

Editor/Subversion:

- Coda (Panic/macos)

Answer (score 1):

I use dreamweaver as a sort of combination text editor with tag highlighting ability and integrated ftp. I just like the way it feels, I know its overkill and don't need/use the majority of its features. When just throwing a single page together or quick editing, I use a text editor like notepad++ or gedit and filezilla. I like the post with the firebug suggestion though, I might break out of my comfort environment and try the "everything from a browser" approach :D

Answer (score 0):

**SO:** Linux

**Editors:** Gedit (with a couple of plugins) or vim (if editing something remotely)

**Browser:** Firefox (with [Webdeveloper](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) and [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/))

Answer (score 0):

eclipse with pdt or notepadd++ on windows 
gedit on Linux

all kept in subversion or git repository. the deployment is handled by a phing build script. that optimizes and deploys the site.

Answer (score 0):

I use **Visual Studio** since our back-end development is based on .NET platform.

VS offers syntax highlighting and also intellisense for both XHTML and CSS which is super handy.

Apart from that:

- Firefox with Firebug and Dev Toolbar
- IE8 with Dev Toolbar
- [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) to quckly test stuff on IE6,7
- Virtual Machine to run **CLEAN** versions of IE6 and IE7 for hardcore debugging (say what you want, no tool will ever render website 1:1 the way original, virgin browser does)
- Opera, Safar, Chrome
- Notepad++ if my too lazy to wait for VS to load

Answer (score 0):

**ASP.net** and **Adobe Flex Builder** for Client Development. 
**Flash** and Microsoft **Expressions** 2 for Images, Animations, Labels etc ...
**C#,Java Script, Action Script** is used for Client and Server side scripting.
**JAVA** is used for middle ware/Web Services. 
**Fiddler** for script debugging and HTTP traffic checking. 
**SoapUI** for web services Testing.

We targeted Firefox and IE for Browsing.
**Windows XP** is widely Used OS.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use some combination of [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) and [Chrome's developer tools](http://www.chromium.org/devtools) for my personal projects, or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) if it's a Java app.

Though generally there's relatively little HTML coding being done, it's generally a lot of Python/Django or Java/GWT and just enough HTML to glue it together.